# Sciences in toki pona

Tags: toki-pona, translation

I managed to translate a lot of things but I'm stuck on a word.
How to say "physics" (knowledge of the nature) in toki pona? A proposition for "nature" would also be appreciated.

> linguistics: sona toki
>
> geology: sona ma
>
> medicine: sona pimejo
>
> mechanics: sona wawa
>
> quantum mechanics: sona lili
>
> ...

I did not find any solution on https://glosbe.com/en/mis_tok/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sona lon*. science of existence

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is used by people in the Toki Pona community to refer to  physics?

Comment: The tp community does not use physics a lot, that is why I asked a question :)

Answer (score 5):

It might be *sona pi ijo tawa* —knowledge of moving things— or *sona pi ijo ante* —knowledge of things that change.

Comment: I think "pona tawa" is enough but it describes cinetics which is only a part of physics.

Comment: _pona tawa_ is "peace in movement".  I think you'd rather say _sona tawa_ for "cinetics". 

Comment: Yes I misspelled that ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this be *sona **pi** ijo tawa* and *sona **pi** ijo ante*?  Since it is the *ijo* that moves and changes rather than the *sona*.

Comment: Yes, I think adding the "pi" word makes the phrase easier to understand.  I have updated my answer. Kudos to you! 

Answer (score 4):

*sijelo* is "body, physical state", so you could use *sona sijelo*; physicists would probably like *sona ale* or *sona ali*, "knowledge of everything" :)

Comment: Great suggestion but I feel "sina sijelo" works better for medicine. Moreover, "sona ali" is overconsideration.

Comment: I agree with the point about medicine; my _sona ali_ suggestion was somewhat tongue in cheek. But then, you trade simplicity for precision in toki pona, so I would still see it as a valid choice in the context of sciences.

Answer (score 4):

To capture all of physics, perhaps "sona pi pali ijo" or simply "sona pali" (a knowledge of action). I prefer the former, since persons may tend to think only of human action with the latter, which may translate to "behavioral science", whereas the former is a bit more precise.

Physics is a general field that focuses on the behavior of things in our universe, finding explanations for their actions and the interactions that occur between things. The term is also a little more precise than "sona ijo", since Physics doesn't (correct me if I'm wrong) really answer questions like 'what structure a thing has', but would rather more specifically answer 'how did the thing's structure come to be'.